# how to add a private message

Tags: docusignapi

Using the DocuSign api and I can't seem to find anywhere on how to add a private message to a signer.  I know this is possible through DocuSign itself--  [send a private message](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-add-messages)-- but using the api doesn't seem to include this.  I checked at the envelope level and at the signer level but I don't see a field to include a private message.  Is there a place I missed where one can include a private message to a signer in the email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data object you're looking for is simply called `note` and can be found on the recipient type definition (ie signer, agent, carbon copy, etc).

Here's the API Reference for the property under the `signer` object:
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/#definitions--note

---

**Details**: A note sent to the recipient in the signing email. This note is unique to this recipient. In the user interface, it appears near the upper left corner of the document on the signing screen.

Maximum Length: 1000 characters.

---

**Example**:

```
"recipients": 
 {
    "signers": [
     {
        "email": "sally@email.com",
        "name": "Sally Doe",
        "note": "This is a private email note only for Sally.",

        ...
```